# How do I create a SQL DB from an Oracle dump file?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle10g, etl

I am new to Oracle but experienced in MSSQL, I have dump file of an Oracle DB and I want to import both the schema and the data from this dump file to MSSQL. How do I create an MSSQL DB from an Oracle dump file?

Steps or a link to the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the "dump file" you're referring to is a .dmp file that was created using either the classic or the DataPump version of the Oracle export utility (`exp` or `expdp`), what you have is an Oracle proprietary binary file format.  It's not designed to be readable by anything other than Oracle's import utility (classic or DataPump depending on which version was used to create the file).  There are some third party tools that claim to be able to read this particular file format and that would let you potentially create a database from a .dmp file but those are generally commercial products and I've never personally used them.

Were it me, assuming that you need to start from the .dmp file, I'd install an Oracle database, import the .dmp file into that Oracle database, and then use your ETL tool of choice (i.e. SSIS since you're experienced with SQL Server) to move the data from one database to the other.  If it's an option, of course, you could connect directly to the actual source Oracle database rather than using the .dmp file to create a populate a newly created Oracle database.

If the "dump file" that you're referring to is something else (i.e. a plain text script of SQL statements), you may have a different set of options.

Comment: Thanks Justin, Like you said the dump file is created using exp utility and I have Oracle 11g installed on my VM. I have already created the oracle database from the dump file using Oracle's DB configuration assistant and imported the dump file to the new Oracle DB. The issue I am having is connecting to this DB from SSIS package , any idea what should the setting be for the package and Oracle Listener?

Comment: @DavidLA - OK.  Then it just becomes a matter of writing the ETL to pull the data from the (static, right?) Oracle database and load it into the SQL Server database.  That's a reasonably straightforward thing to do in SSIS.

Comment: @Jutin Cave, thanks again, any utility that can be used to get SQL .bak file from the Oracle db.

Comment: @DavidLA - None that I'm aware of though I wouldn't be shocked if some commercial product tried to implement this.  I'd tend to avoid proprietary file formats, though, both Oracle .dmp and SQL Server .bak files, unless there were no other option.  If you don't want to use SSIS, you could write the Oracle data to a flat file and use `bcp` to load it into SQL Server-- that at least gets you away from proprietary formats and into something that is relatively easy for humans to understand & debug.